# Anime, appeared on Netflix, boy with blue hair carries a sword and fights underground worm monsters, maybe in Tokyo

Tags: story-identification, tv, anime

This anime used to play on Netflix.

- It has a boy with blue hair
- I think he carries a sword and fights underground-worm-monsters
- It takes place in Tokyo, I think

Anyone know what this anime is?

Comment: On Netflix of which country? European catalogs are different from American ones :)

Comment: Could you take a quick look at the following two links, and see if there are any other details you could add to your question? https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-story-id-question?rq=1

Comment: American Netflix. :) @Lyzvaleska

Comment: @ConMan Unfortunately I don't have any more details, it's okay if you don't know though, thank you for trying, same to you Lyzvaleska :) I really appreciate it!

Comment: Thanks! How did you find out? After looking at this Youtube video, I think you're right. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ASbgIVNuAV0

Comment: Don’t look at YouTube videos, trust us fine Stack Exchange users! I believe the name F.R.I.D.A.Y. is seen hand-written on a disk or something in *Age of Ultron*. I feel like it’s also mentioned in dialogue somewhere (maybe just by Spider-Man in *Homecoming*, as [F.R.I.D.A.Y. runs his suit too](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spider-Man:_Homecoming#Cast)).

Comment: Please don't change your questions into totally different ones after posting them. The original anime-ID question is one that people had already put time into thinking about, and that somebody might be able to answer in the future. The Captain America question is a *new* and equally valid question, and [you can post it as such](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) without removing this question.

Comment: Ah! I was wondering why some of the earlier comments mentioned anime, and American Netflix.

Comment: @Randal'Thor I'm sorry, but in my defense you guys wouldn't let me post another question until after 24 hrs because of all the unwarranted downvotes I got on my second question. And also it's not my fault that I don't remember this anime correctly, so I feel like I should've been able to ask another question. But I know what I did was wrong.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite Sorry for wasting your time spent. I know that doesn't fix anything though.

Comment: That’s quite alright — this is a place where I come to read and occasionally write about the miniutae of goofy movies, it’s pretty much all time-wasting.

Comment: I don't know how long the question rate limit lasts for, but you should be able to post your other question now.